# T-SQL Select minimum values from different records of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a query in which I count the number of events per day:

```
**Date**        **NumberOfEvents**
2017-11-1       7
2017-11-2       11
2017-11-3       3
...
2017-11-8       24
2017-11-9       6
2017-11-10      10
2017-11-11      9
...
2017-11-22      22
2017-11-23      11
2017-11-24      14
2017-11-25      17
...      
2017-11-28      16
2017-11-29      21
2017-11-30      6
...
```

Then let's say I would define a variable `@StartingDay ='2017-11-3'`

I would like to get a query with the minimum value for the same week day +-1 day for the next 4 weeks after @StartingDay, p.ex:

```
**Period**                   **DateWithMin**   **MinNumberOfEvents**
2017-11-09 To 2017-11-11     2017-11-9         6
2017-11-16 To 2017-11-18     2017-11-17        8
2017-11-23 To 2017-11-25     2017-11-23        11
2017-11-30 To 2017-12-02     2017-11-30        6
```

I believe I would have to cycle through the different periods to search for the min, but I can't find a way to cycle.

Comment: I'm not following your expected results... why is `2017-11-09` to `2017-11-11` the first result when the `@StartingDay` is `2017-11-03`?  What do you pick when there are ties?  The earliest date?

Comment: 1. It's the next week same day (2017-11-10) +- 1 day
2. In this particular case, it does not matter, it can be any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to generate the `From` and `To` dates with a recursive CTE, apply a `Row_Number()` to the results to find the `Min` per grouping, and select only those results:

```
Declare @StartingDay    Date = '2017-11-03',
        @NumWeeks       Int = 4

;With Dates As
(
    Select  DateFrom    = DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Week, 1, @StartingDay)),
            DateTo      = DateAdd(Day, 1, DateAdd(Week, 1, @StartingDay))
    Union All
    Select  DateFrom    = DateAdd(Week, 1, DateFrom),
            DateTo      = DateAdd(Week, 1, DateTo)  
    From    Dates
    Where   DateTo < DateAdd(Day, 1, DateAdd(Week, @NumWeeks, @StartingDay))
), Results As
(
    Select  PeriodFrom      = D.DateFrom,
            PeriodTo        = D.DateTo,
            NumberOfEvents  = Y.NumberOfEvents,
            RN              = Row_Number() Over (Partition By D.DateFrom, D.DateTo 
                                                 Order By Y.NumberOfEvents),
            Date            = Y.Date
    From    YourTable   Y
    Join    Dates       D   On  Y.Date Between D.DateFrom And D.DateTo
)
Select  PeriodFrom, 
        PeriodTo, 
        DateWithMin         = Date, 
        MinNumberOfEvents   = NumberOfEvents
From    Results
Where   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo and date arithmetic to get the time periods and groups:

```
select min(date), max(date), min(NumberOfEvents)
from t
where (datediff(day, @startingday, date) % 7) in (0, 1, 6) and
      date > dateadd(day, 1, @startingday) and
      date <= dateadd(day, 4 * 7 + 1, @startingday)
group by (datediff(day, @startingday, date) + 1) / 7;
```

Getting the date of the minimum event is more troublesome.  Here is one method:

```
select min(date), max(date), min(NumberOfEvents),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_at_min
from (select t.*, v.grp,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by numberofevents) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values ((datediff(day, @startingday, date) + 1) / 7)) v(grp)
     ) t
where (datediff(day, @startingday, date) % 7) in (0, 1, 6) and
      date > dateadd(day, 1, @startingday) and
      date <= dateadd(day, 4 * 7 + 1, @startingday)
group by grp;
```

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the second part of the code. I get some null results in date_at_min. You are looking for the minimum value in each week (seqnum=1). However, if the minimum of a week is outside the 3 day period, it returns null. It should search for the min seqnum in the 3 day period, right?